# Supervisord dies completely if program runs for less than 1 second?

Tags: supervisord

A program that runs for less than 1 second, every second on Supervisord causes the Supervisord to not run the program again. Why could that be?

I run "GET http://someurl.com/some/url" every second, and whenever this runs for less than 1 second (i.e. if I exclude "sleep(1)") then it will only run once, and never again. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set:

```
startsecs=0
```

in supervisord.conf

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Supervisord log file mostly in `/tmp/supervisord.log` if there is not enough information why Supervisord is restarting your program try to set logging of your program in Supervisord configuration file `/etc/supervisord.conf` and look why your program is crashing:

```
[your_program_config:program]
stdout_logfile = /your_program/path/logs/your_program.log
redirect_stderr = true
```